# How can I check the AngularJS UI-Router state from within another controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular's [**UI-Router**](https://ui-router.github.io/) as shown below to do URL-routing in my web-app as shown below:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState1', {
    url: '/state1',
    templateUrl: 'state1.html',
    controller: 'MyState1Ctrl'
  });

$stateProvider.state('myState2', {
    url: '/state2',
    templateUrl: 'state2.html',
    controller: 'MyState2Ctrl'
  });
```

Within each of the two template files `state1.html`, `state2.html`, I have my navigation bar directive: `<myapp-navigation-bar></myapp-navigation-bar>`. Here is the navigation bar's controller:

```
raptorApp.controller('NavigationCtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {return "something";}, function (objVal) {
        console.log('Hello from NavigationCtrl!');
    },true);
});
```

But I want the navigation bar to behave differently based on weather it is in `myState1` or `myState2`. How can I detect from within `NavigationCtrl` which state it is in?

Answer (score 2):

we can always place anything into `$scope` and `watch` it. Even the `$state` service and its `current.name`. Something like *(just a draft)*

```
raptorApp.controller('NavigationCtrl', function($scope, $state){
    var self = this;
    $scope.state = $state;
    $scope.$watch("state.current.name", function (objVal) {
        console.log('current state name changed');
    },true);
});
```

*NOTE: never forget to remove such watch on destroy*

But with UI-Router.. there are better ways. Much better ways:

- named views
- multiple views

So we can have a parent state, with a view called **`'myapp-navigation-bar'`** and that could be filled by each state... with a different implementation. See this for detailed how to and example

#### [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)

#### [How do I load UI-router ui-view templates that are nested 3 states deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29441976/1679310)

Comment: Radim, I just posted a question on your other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800644/nested-states-or-views-for-layout-with-leftbar-in-ui-router

Could you please answer it?

Comment: @SaqibAli Check the example in that answer. IN that plunker.. click on the right upper corner icon... "launch the preview in a separate window" .. you will see any url once state is changed